# bootstrap-vue How do I change the size of the my cards header?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

## How can I change the size of my cards header?

```
<b-card header = "We are certified data installers" md="5" class="card" bg-variant="dark" style="border-color: rgb(235, 100, 33); font-size: 30px;">
    
    We are skilled in getting you set up or helping when you need changes made, as your business changes or expands.

 
  </b-card>
```

I am able to change all of the text at once but I am trying to target just the header of my card

Answer (score 1):

You can use "b-card-subtititle" instead

and it's easy to change size

check document https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/card

```js
<b-card
  no-body
  style="max-width: 20rem;"
  img-src="https://placekitten.com/380/200"
  img-alt="Image"
  img-top
>
  <b-card-body>
    <b-card-title>Card Title</b-card-title>
    <b-card-sub-title class="mb-2" style="font-size: 12px">Card Sub Title</b-card-sub-title>
    <b-card-text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
        content.
    </b-card-text>
  </b-card-body>
</b-card>
```